# Remove all but newest file from all sub directories

Tags: linux, directory, directory-traversal

I have found the following which will list the files in all subdirectories, hide the last 5, and then delete the rest:

```
find -type f -printf '%T@ %P\n' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- | head -n -5 | xargs rm
```

Unfortunately if I don't know how many subdirectories there are, it won't delete the correct number of files.   Does anyone have a way to transverse each directory, and then delete all but the newest of file in each subdirectory?

Directory structure would be the following:

-> Base Directory -> Parent Directory -> Child directory

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a script.

It would be a recursive function:

- call function: rm_files(base_dir)
- list all directories
- if there are directories go through on the list and call rm_files(act_dir) for each item
- else (if there is no directories):

  - list all files
  - delete all files but the newest
- return from function

In case lot of subdirectories it may be memory problem because of the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I found I was able to do what I needed to do with the following one liner:

```
find . -name *.* -mmin +59 -delete > /dev/null
```